# Is believing in superstition Haram

Tags: halal-haram, kufr, belief

There are many superstitions around us and people utter them because of arrogance. Is believing in those things Haram?

Jazakallah Khairan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

We are not to believe in that because Allah the Exalted said in the Qur’an:

وما خلقتُ الجِنَّ والإنسَ إلا ليعبُدون

Ayahs 56, 57, 58 in Surat Adh-Dhariyat mean: Allah created the Jinn and Humans and ordered them to worship Him.

So everything including those superstition belong to Allah Azawajal, we just has to believe in Allah and always remember Allah as Allah said in Qur'an 13:28 that

"Those who believe (in the Oneness of Allah - Islamic Monotheism), and whose hearts find rest in the remembrance of Allah, Verily, in the remembrance of Allah do hearts find rest."

So we just have to remember Allah always and forget about those superstition

Wasalamu alaikum

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

Believing in superstition is Minor Shirk

Go away from these

Comment: Nice one, we really appreciate your answer, help us to development our dream society please visit [tour] for more information. Wasalamu alaikum